# How to import my local svn project to new created svn repository and keep history information

Tags: svn

The svn server of our company has crashed, and all data lost.

The is a project with latest data in a development machine, I want to import it to new created svn server, and keep the commit history information(at least the version number), then let others switch there project to the new server.

Is it possible? And how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a backup you can restore it to a new machine using this:

```
svnadmin load "C:\SvnData\Project" < "C:\Backup.dump"
```

If you don't have a backup you can export then import the current working copy into a new repository but you will lose the versioning history.